# No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin for authorization token but the URLs are set

Tags: linkedin-api

The Linkedin API is tough to reach to say the least... :) Or maybe I'm just dumb, who knows!

I have already retrieved the code and it is passed along.

I have this request setup as per the docs (sorry for the font size, trying to fit everything)

[image]

However, when I attempt this request through a browser, I am greeted with this CORS error:

[image]

Here are the current URLs setup in my Linked App Auth section:

[image]

I put both in there just to cover all my bases. Still getting the error. Conceptually, I get it, you should not be able to call the API if your domain is not recognized by Linkedin. However, the redirect URLs, as I understand it, bridge that gap and are 'allowed domains'.

Any idea how to fix this? Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Generally its server site issue, But you can override this issue from client side using PROXYURL

```js
const proxyURL = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const requestURL = YOUR URL;
$.getJSON(proxyURL + requestURL, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})
```